# Function: Table as return-value

Tags: mysql, function, return-value, stored-functions

I usually work with MSSQL-Server where I can return a table-like dataset to the caller of the function. I understand that this is not possible in MySQL. What is the best way in MySQL, what are good ways to get the same result.

Should I work with temp-tables? I'm glad for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think temp tables are your only answer. You can't 'use' the return of a stored procedure and a stored function can only return one value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of the table you wish to return.

If it is a single column you could return it as a delimited string, and parse that.

Otherwise, you will need to use a temp table.